# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.view.View.onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: java, android, kotlin, handler

I'm getting this generic error on Android Vitals, the log doesn't report the activity.

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  at android.view.View.onRestoreInstanceState (View.java:20879)
  at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState (View.java:20851)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState (ViewGroup.java:4067)
  at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState (View.java:20829)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreViewState (Fragment.java:689)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreViewState (Fragment.java:3151)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated (Fragment.java:3142)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated (FragmentStateManager.java:579)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java:264)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStore.java:113)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1433)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManager.java:2977)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentManager.java:2895)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentController.java:263)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:351)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java:246)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1435)
  at android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:8097)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity (ActivityThread.java:3571)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence (TransactionExecutor.java:221)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath (TransactionExecutor.java:201)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:173)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:97)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2144)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:240)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8000)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:603)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

The error happens on devices on Android 11 and Android 12. Has anyone encountered this error or can you see where the error might be happening?

Comment: I have seen one from Lenovo X606X (Lenovo Tab M10 FHD Plus) Android 10 (SDK 29)